# Hornetq and IBM Websphere MQ Comparison

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, ibm-mq, middleware, hornetq

I would like to get some opinion regarding these two JMS providers in terms of :

1. Documentation
2. Easy to use
3. Features
4. Standard Conformance

I would like to use it together with NetBeans and GlassFish.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar with HornetQ and can't provide a good comparison.  However, I've retagged your question with netbeans and glassfish which get a lot more traffic and might gen up some responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. HornetQ has a concise documentation on hornetq.org. Maybe it's just me but I often find myself lost on the redbooks on IBM while looking for the right documentation.
2. HornetQ has very few dependencies making it easy to manage.
3. You would need to compare feature by feature, but last time I looked at it HornetQ has more features.
4. Both are JMS compliant. However with HornetQ you have standard syncs out of the box.

In a another note, I made myself a performance comparison between HornetQ and WebSphere MQ and HornetQ was faster in all the usecases.  I can't publish the actual comparisson due to license issues with IBM.

Regarding glass fish you will have to integrate the Resource Adapter of HornetQ, but we haven't dedicated many resources on testing it.

As for NetBeans that should be really easy.

Comment: The WMQ product docs are here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp and they are also supplied with the WMQ install media.  Better to start there than with the Redbooks.  What does "standard syncs out of the box" mean?  WMQ provides a JMS compliant implementation out of the box so I'm not understanding the distinction you are trying to make.

Comment: A lot of providers will cheat making the default configuration for benchmark purposes, disabling syncs on transactions. What's only useful for fake benchmarks.

Comment: I find the hornetq has better documentation and example.

Comment: The answer implies that perhaps IBM has disabled syncpoint with WMQ out of the box. For the record, WMQ does not disable syncpoint. There is a default setting of whether syncpoint is used and this setting differs by platform.  But the default only takes effect if the application coder fails to specify whether or not to use it.  It's merely an option on the PUT or GET.  For persistent messages with more than one message per transaction, syncs can actually be *faster* in WMQ since it optimizes write-behind until the COMMIT at which point all updates are hardened to disk.

Comment: @mqrus: In any comparison I always make with any other JMS provider, I always make with syncs on. To make sync=false would be the same as ignore the semantic and need to sync the disk on commit.. It's a bad choice that is silly and only suitable for dumb benchmarks. I never to that kind of comparison.